# css div tag float issue

Tags: html, css

[image: without entering into this position.][image]

On resizing browser , I want to get the result shown in second picture without getting into position shown in first picture.
http://jsfiddle.net/gtczu/19/

```html
<div id="lft-widget" style=" border:solid red 3px"></div>
<div id="rgt-widget" style=" border:solid blue 3px"></div>
<div id="center-widget" style="border:solid green 1px"></div>
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#center-widget {
    position :relative;
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 0 15px 30px;
}
#lft-widget {
    width:234px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    padding:25px 25px 0 0px;
}
#rgt-widget {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 2px 22px 72px 30px;
    position:relative;
}
```

What I want is when I resize browser , `#center-widget` should float to the bottom of `#rgt-widget`. this is successful in this case but while resizing it floats bottom of `#lft-widget` and then it float bottom of `#rgt-widget`.  I want it to directly float bottom of `#rgt-widget`.

I want to achieve this.

without getting into this position.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing your point but are you trying to implement something like this: http://masonry.desandro.com/?

Comment: Your 'center-widget' floats left because there is no space to float right, - you set a static width to those elements. Can you draw that do you want to achieve? Let's say u have such dimensions: browser width: 600px, left widget: 200px, center: 200px, right: 300px.

Comment: why's your left widget on the right and your right widget on the left? [anyway, think this may be what you are after](http://jsfiddle.net/6MWp6/)

Comment: removed ASP.Net tag as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 clear:left;
```

to the center-widget css and it should fall underneath the rgt-widget div when you expand the window.